# can't update empty relationship

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

I've got `@ManyToMany` relation beetwen my two models (User - Superior)

No when User has empty `List<Superior>` and I do something like this

```
Superior superior = Superior.findById(1); // yes superior exists and isn't null
user.superiors.add(superior);
user.update(user.id) // or user.save()
```

nothing happens

BUT when I already have some items in `user.superiors` and I don same thing (add a new one) and than I update everything works and connection is added.

What is going on ?

// EDIT

biesior`s answer is the good one
but come on - this is sick :/

Comment: Apparently this solves your problem: `if (user.superiors.size() == 0) user.superiors = new ArrayList<Superior>(); user.superiors.add(superior);` however  I have no Idea why is this required...